# Bug de Permissão no Serviço de Aplicativo do Azure

Tags: wordpress, sistema-de-arquivos, microsoft-azure, file-permission

Eu tenho um serviço de aplicativo na Azure rodando wordpress.

Certo dia, ao atualizar um plugin, este não só parou de funcionar como o painel *Kudu* não consegue visualizá-lo.

Observe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consigo listar dentro da pasta pelo console na parte de baixo da tela, entretanto o visualizador do *Kudu* não consegue visualizá-lo.

Tentei alterar através do *chmod* as permissões mas não altera nada. Já apaguei a pasta e copiei outra. Já renomeei incluindo outra e nada.

O que é peculiar é ao acessar essa pasta através do *KUDU*, aparece uma mensagem da Azure indicando que minha sessão está espirada, mas não está porque continuo utilizando o painel após clicar em OK. O usuário e o grupo aparecem como desconhecido pela linha de comando *ls -l*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu acessar pelo navegador, apontando até a url final, recebo a mensagem "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.".

Já abri um suporte na Microsoft mas até agora não houve retorno de solução.

Parece ser um erro de permissão no sistema de arquivos que a Microsoft utiliza no Serviço de Aplicativo.

Alguém mais já passou por isso e consegue fornecer um caminho para a luz?

Comment: Eu tenho um suporte aberto na Microsoft com o técnico dizendo: Reinstala! Não tenho como te ajudar porque não tenho acesso. É um jogo de empurra pra cá e empurra pra lá. Parece até brasileiro! Vamos lá, Kendrick, uma forcinha pra resolver, né?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O suporte da Microsoft concluiu que existe um plugin que pode ser utilizado no Serviço de Aplicativo chamado [Composer](https://github.com/SyntaxC4-MSFT/ComposerExtension) que não permite a palavra "vendor" e com isso, ocorre o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desabilitamos esta extensão e o site voltou a funcionar normalmente.

Espero que ajude.